# VB6 - Passing MSHFlexGrid as argument to class module function, Windows 8.1 +

Tags: vb6

I have a public class method in a DLL that accepts an MSHFlexGrid parameter in the form of a variant.

```
Public Sub PrintReport(ByVal gridToPrint as Variant)
```

I specify the parameter as variant in order to avoid the compile error:

> "Private object modules cannot be used in public object modules as
>   parameters or return types for public procedures, as public data
>   members, or as fields of public user defined types"

My main application instantiates an instance of this class and calls the PrintReport method, passing in an MSHFlexGrid.

```
Dim clsPrint As PrintProject.clsPrint
Set clsPrint = New PrintProject.clsPrint
clsPrint.PrintReport gridToPrint
```

where **gridToPrint** is the name of the MSHFlexGrid control on my form.

This logic has worked for years until Windows 8.1 came around.

Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 generate a **type mismatch** error on calling the PrintReport method.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

I would have thought it to be an environment issue, but this happens consistently on all installations running either Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, whereas Windows 8 and lower work well.

Please excuse my ignorance if I haven't structured my question properly. First time poster, long time user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the trick you used by passing the grid as a Variant no longer works. It seems as if this should not have worked on any version  of Windows. Perhaps try to solve the original error now (which is nasty enough in itself).

Comment: The DLL should have had a reference set to MSHFLXGD.OCX and that would permit proper early-bound arguments.  Using a Variant is a bit odd (Object makes more sense here) but either should work.  It seems far more likely you have a deployment flaw than anything else though, I haven't seen anything in Windows 8.1 or 10 that would have such an impact.  This seems far more likely a case of "Works On My Machine." http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/

Comment: i would try passing the grid as an object type instead.